# Kubernetes, conectar backend a base de datos mongodb deplegada en otro namespace

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

Estoy aquí haciendo algo de research para aprender sobre kubernetes.
Me he desplegado en local un cluster de kubernetes usando Kind, y estoy tratando de desplegar el backend de un proyecto y una base de datos mongo.
Para mongo estoy unsando el helm de bitnami/monogdb.

cunado despliego el backend y mongodb en el mimso namespace (el de default), no tengo problemas en conectar el backend a mongo a través de su uri:

```
mongodb://root:password@mongodb:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
```

Ahora bien, si despliego el backend en un namespace, por ejemplo, "backend", y el mongodb en otro namespace, por ejemplo, "data". No consigo conectarlos.

Lo que estoy intentando es crear un externalservice, tal que asi:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongodb-external-service
  namespace: backend
  labels:
    microservice: mongodb
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mongodb.data.scv.cluster.local
```

de forma que entiendo que la cadena de conexión de mongo ahora seria:

```
mongodb://root:password@mongodb-external-service:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
```

sin embargo, no consigo conectar el backend.

¿Qué me estoy dejando en el tintero?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Vale, pues creo que he dado con la clave: No hace falta un externalservice.

al final la cadena de conexión seria:

```
mongodb://root:G2J1I50mxc@<nombre_servicio_mongo>.<namespace>:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
```

Espero que le ayude a todo aquel que lo necesite!